# Read from a configuration file in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to read a configuration file(conf.txt) in Nifi. Based on the path provided in this file i want to configure the paths(eg:hdfs file path , input directory path) in the nifi processors.

Is it possible with the existing processors or should i go for a custom processor.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure [custom properties](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#custom_properties) as part of Apache NiFi's Variable Registry feature, which makes properties from your external file available to NiFi Expression Language expressions.  Using Expression Language, you can configure many processors with your externally-defined variables.

**conf/nifi.properties**

```
# external properties files for variable registry
# supports a comma delimited list of file locations
nifi.variable.registry.properties=./conf/custom.properties
```

**conf/custom.properties**

```
my.prop1=value1
my.prop2=value2
...
```

**In Expressions**

```
${my.prop1}
```